# Uso de instanceof

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos

Criar uma classe abstrata `Conta`, e outras duas classes concretas `ContaF` e `ContaJ` que herdam da classe principal. Criar outra classe com um método que recebe uma lista de `contaF` e `ContaJ` e `ArrayList<Conta>` e calcule quantos elementos tem em `ContaF` e `ContaJ`

Estou quase finalizando:

```
public class InstanciaDe 
{

public static void main( String[] args )
{

    ContaF Rafael = new ContaF();

    ContaJ Roberto = new ContaJ();      

    ContaJ Carlos = new ContaJ();  

    ArrayList<Conta> lista = new ArrayList<Conta>();        

    lista.add(Rafael);
    lista.add(Roberto);
    lista.add(Carlos);

    for(int i=0 ; i < lista.size() ; i++){              


        if (lista.get(i) instanceof ContaF) {

        }       

        if (lista.get(i) instanceof ContaJ) {

        }
    }  
}
}
```

Como posso guardar a quantidade pelo `instanceof` de cada e depois exibir?

Comment: `int nContaF = 0; if(lista.get(i) instanceof ContaF) nContaf++;`

Comment: Obrigado, estava pensando em algo parecido.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É só criar um contador:

```
import java.util.*;

class InstanciaDe {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        int contaF = 0;
        int contaJ = 0;
        ContaF Rafael = new ContaF();
        ContaJ Roberto = new ContaJ();
        ContaJ Carlos = new ContaJ();
        ArrayList<Conta> lista = new ArrayList<Conta>();        
        lista.add(Rafael);
        lista.add(Roberto);
        lista.add(Carlos);
        for(int i = 0 ; i < lista.size() ; i++) {
            if (lista.get(i) instanceof ContaF) {
                contaF++;
            }       
            if (lista.get(i) instanceof ContaJ) {
                contaJ++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(contaF);
        System.out.println(contaJ);
    }
}
class Conta {}
class ContaF extends Conta {}
class ContaJ extends Conta {}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/v2VHLq). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/wezoqvgb-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Typing/Instanceof.java).

Comment: Foi muito útil, obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.*;

class Conta {}
class ContaF extends Conta {}
class ContaJ extends Conta {}

class InstanciaDe {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ContaF Rafael = new ContaF();

        ContaJ Roberto = new ContaJ();      

        ContaJ Carlos = new ContaJ();  

        ArrayList<Conta> lista = new ArrayList<Conta>();        

        lista.add(Rafael);
        lista.add(Roberto);
        lista.add(Carlos);

        System.out.println(getInstanceCount(contas, ContaF.class));
        System.out.println(getInstanceCount(contas, ContaJ.class));
    }

    public static int getInstanceCount(List<Conta> contas, Class<? extends Conta> class1) {
        int count = 0;

        for (Conta conta : contas) {
            if (conta.getClass().equals(class1)) {
                count++;
            }
        }

        return count;
    }
}
```